# access: how to add a workorder to a customer

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a noob question but he, i'm learning :-)

I'm making a form with the following tables `1 tblCustomers` and `1 tblWorkorders`.

**My question is:**

When I add a customer to a new record, this person is stored in the table: `tblCustomers` this is going fine.

The problem is that I also have a table: `tblWorkorders`, in this table I store all the technical information, sollutions and the customers belongings. (adapter, notebook bag etc etc)

My problem excists when for example a customer named John Doe comes back with another problem 2 weeks later. In the table `tblWorkorders` should be 2 records with the problems of *John Doe* I think it has something to do with relationships between the tables, can someone tell me where to find a good example or when it's a short story, how to do this?

Comment: Your question will be very difficult to answer without specifics on how you built the app and a more precise description of what code isn't working.

Comment: To second @JohnFx, you say *what* you're doing but nothing about how. Nobody can begin to answer your question until you provide details on how you're trying to accomplish your task and what, specifically, is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very difficult to explain this concept and start you off from scratch. Be prepared for further research on different item. Here is a place to start:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/guide-to-table-relationships-HA010120534.aspx

The following is how you would use your tables:

You need to have a common field in both tables (it can be more than one field, but let's keep it simple). The easy way is to have a CustomerID field that is a Data Type field set to: AutoNumber (It does just what it says.).

tblWorkOrders will have the same field (doesn't have to be the same name, but let's keep it simple) BUT, the Data Type is: Number Field Size: Long Interger.

If you're able to use:  Database Tools | Relationships, and join the two tables by this field, developing forms and reports is a lot easier.

Your form will be based on the tblCustomers table (I know, let's keep it simple.) and a Sub Form will use the tblWorkorders table and the 'Link Master Fields' and the 'Link Child Fields' will use the CustomerID from each table.

Comment: thank you very much, i think I got the clue, something still doesnt work, but i'll ask that in a other question.